# Mongo Restore shows no Reachable servers error in sharded cluster environment on AWS?

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb, shell, amazon-web-services

Can someone help me as I am stuck in this problem for many days. My client created a remote database in a sharded cluster environment on AWS and he gave me credentials to access. I am able to connect to the remote cluster database using mongo shell. I have dumps available which need to restore on remote DB but when I ran the below command on mongo shell it shows me error:

**mongorestore --host Test-shard-0/test-shard-00-00-fk4je.mongodb.net:27017,test-shard-00-01-fk4je.mongodb.net:27017,test-shard-00-02-fk4je.mongodb.net:27017 --db admin --username jeff --password jeff11 dump/staffing/companies.bson**

Error: Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers.

Though, I am able to connect to database easily using mongo shell and see the databases/collections but can't figure out why mongorestore not working. Tried different things but every time above error appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--ssl flag was missing from command.

mongorestore --host Test-shard-0/test-shard-00-00-fk4je.mongodb.net:27017,test-shard-00-01-fk4je.mongodb.net:27017,test-shard-00-02-fk4je.mongodb.net:27017 --db admin **--ssl** --username jeff --password jeff11 dump/staffing/companies.bson

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing the --port 27017 part. According to the documentation

```
mongorestore --host mongodb1.example.net --port 37017 --username user --password pass /opt/backup/mongodump-2011-10-24
```

this is the example of restoring document.

Comment: Its a cluster environment port is already there. Btw. the one you mentioned also didn't work.